# Rearrange cells in a Open Office spreadsheet, from data in cols to data in rows

Tags: openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I have this spreadsheet (Open Office) and all the data is filled in so they form a col, 
and I would like to change this so they fill a row instead.
Kind of mirror the doc in both axis.

This is how it looks today

```
       D1 D2 D3 D4 D5
Name1  01 02 03 04 05
Name2  10 11 12 13 14
```

And then I would like to transform the data so the data comes in rows instead.

```
    Name1 Name2
D1     01    10
D2     02    11
D3     03    12
D4     04    13
D5     05    14
```

Is there a function in Open Office (Libre Office) that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - just use `Paste special` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) and select `Transpose` from options. [Here](http://openoffice.blogs.com/openoffice/2007/02/very_cool_featu.html)'s a nice description of this feature.

Comment: Nice that works like a charm :)